# How do I Make the "Anime Girl Warrior Physique" Realistic?

Tags: biology, evolution, hard-science, alternate-history, low-fantasy

In some  Anime, Women look nothing at all like men, yet  are capable of nearly the same exact feats of physical strength:

[image]

*Image from Dragon Ball Super*

Is there a way to manipulate biology and evolution to make something like that possible?

I am not asking for a petite 16 year old that can suplex a cow. That’s obviously impossible. But  could there exist someone with the body of  a tomboy but the physical and mental strength of a medieval European soldier in real life?

Comment: The question is fine, but most of the backstory is distracting and unnecessary. It can be summarized as follows: "If something happened to all the men, how long would it take for women to evolve to become just as strong as men?"

Comment: The interesting question is can you have a tribe of [Shauna Coxeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij-VeTlP4nM) who pass on their  monstrous strength to their daughters but not their sons.

Comment: I agree that I think there may be some valid questions in here, but frankly, I'm not gonna read through all of that (why all the "buff anime babe" pictures in the middle?) just to try to answer a couple of questions for you.  I'd advise reposting this but ditching most of your "theory" backstory and just concentrating on the specific questions you want to ask, and asking them as succinctly as possible.  Also, I'd just point out that the difference in physical strength between typical athletic men and women is not actually as large or significant as you might think in most realistic contexts.

Comment: Please remember that we have a strict one question per post policy on this site. As I told you on meta this definitely could do with an editing pass for clarity and to remove extraneous content. Next time you're unsure just use the sandbox to gather feedback first.

Comment: @Daron, the question is NOT fine, because there are 3 questions, and 2 of them are asking for opinions.

Comment: @L.Dutch Two of the three should be removed. I think what I wrote summarizes the asker's concerns nicely in a single question

Comment: On another topic, what are you on about "barely increasing muscle mass"? Your anime babes are jacked AF. Except maybe the first one.

Comment: Oh, this is the [900 words question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9967/80336), right? Well, it's actually... 1571 words long, but that's not important. I'm reading it and check if we can improve it, but I have to ask beforehand : Why did you not try it in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/9966#9966), as suggested? If for instance something there put you off, can you explain it so we can improve it?

Comment: I do not understand *at all* why anybody would believe that women do not have *"the same neurological capacity for bloodshed and violence"* as men. In the Second World War the Soviets deployed several all-female front line combat units, including the famous 588th Night Bomber Regiment, the "[Night Witches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Witches)", distinguished with the Order of the Red Banner and the Order of Suvorov; the Soviet Union is also famous for its female snipers, including Lyudmila Pavlichenko, Roza Shanina, Aliya Moldagulova and Natalya Kovshova (look them up).

Comment: @AlexP - https://www.ox.ac.uk/news/science-blog/roots-aggression

Comment: @Daron (and OP) The anime babes (in the earlier version) do look fairly small and slight, so I suppose that limits the amount of "muscle mass".  (Well, except the red-haired one, who looks kind of weird).  But it looks like being all wiry muscle and no fat within those limits, like a very small body-builder, is within the briefing.

Comment: @A.B. They look strong enough to throw any man I know off a cliff without breaking a sweat.

Comment: @Neuro Added an image. The word "tomboy" has gone out of fashion over the last 20 years. No one really knows what it means anymore.

Comment: Finally got some time; Note that I'm stricter than usual to reopen since it was a pretty bad start, and so need more efforts to change minds ^^'. Your last version is much better than the first one. You still have two distinct questions, one of which you could remove. The last one about gender monomorphism/physical equality doesn't seem to be what you seek, because one valid answer is to weaken men's muscles, rather than increasing women's x). Take out one question and I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @Tortiena - That’s not a valid answer though. I wanna write a story where both men and women can fight in wars but I don’t wanna reduce the strength of one gender just to make that possible.

Comment: Given that men and women fight in wars today what makes you think that you'd need to change anything for this to be possible in your world?

Comment: The question really boils down to "what are the biological differences between women and men and how could evolution have gone differently". e.g. why do women compete separately from men in weightlifting. Or rugby. There are real physical differences. This is actually a biology question (and one that I don't know enough to answer). I think there are some examples in the animal kingdom, though, where females are strong and males are weak. Might be able to draw up some basis for an answer there, too.

Comment: It sounds like the question is "how can women (on average) plausibly be noticeably smaller/slimmer than men, as in anime and to some extent as in real life, but be as strong as men?".  Which seems like a tricky one, but The Square-Cube Law's answer does seem to address it... albeit with some silly side-effects.  It doesn't seem to address the question of *why*, in evolutionary terms, men might be bigger than women if it wasn't to pack in more muscle power, though, and that might be a tricky question.

Answer (score 9):

**No Muscles. No Problem.**

Do not worry. You can safely make your Medieval women  strong as Medieval men. They will not become bulbous and veiny like Goku from Dragonball Z. Because Medieval men were not bulbous and veiny like Goku from Dragonball Z.

**Details:**

[image]

Medieval soldiers were not supermen. Most of them were farmers. Medieval farmers worked 8-12 hours a day and had great strength and endurance. But they did not look like muscle-bound super-studs.

Medieval farmers are extinct. The closest we can find today is people living in the developed world who do manual labour all day. [The above men](https://www.agefotostock.com/age/en/details-photo/two-mali-tribesmen-carrying-wooden-fence-stakes-to-market-bissam-cuttack-rayagader-district-orissa-india-asia/RHA-805-63) are described as Mali Tribesmen from Orissa, India.  Take the above with a grain of salt, since people who do purely manual labour are rare these days. And "tribal tourism" is certainly a big moneymaker.

Also check out [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/@fearlessandfar) who spent some time with the Hadza hunter-gatherers in Tanzania. Again I cannot promise you these people live this way on a daily basis. But Wikipedia at least suggests there are only about 1200 Hadza people. So perhaps they are the rare exception.

Also check out any [tribal people from the Amazon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3IAZq-mGwY). You cannot be sure how these people live when the camera is turned off. But if [they live in deep jungle](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=amazon+rainforest+tribes) then you can tell they don't have cars or mechanized farming. So they do everything by hand.

Dressed differently, the Mali man on the left would be invisible walking down a busy city street in the West. Until you shake his hand and notice he is made of solid iron.

None of these people look like bulky superheroes. They do not have stupid well-defined muscles like Maki Oze from Fire Force:

[image]

A real-life Maki Oze could bench-press more than the average Medieval peasant. But only because she practices bench-pressing every day. The peasant could probably outlast Maki if they were lifting a smaller load. And Maki would certainly crumble if forced to push a plough for 12 hours straight.

For a modern example of what a woman looks like, when she  trains every part of her body, without focusing on appearance, check out olympic climbers. Without her clothes on [Shauna Coxey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij-VeTlP4nM) looks like this:

[image]

and not like this:

[image]

You can see the muscles, but would not suspect she is one of the strongest women on the planet. [But check her out on the wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij-VeTlP4nM). And look at how strong she is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Denser muscular fibers

[Daron's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/238750/21222) is the scientifically correct one. But if you want a simpler (though idiotic) one, make it so that in your world estrogen packs muscular fibers tighter together.

This would mean that Caulifla (the woman in the screenshot at the question) weights about the same as Goku (the man in the screenshot), so they would be at around the same weight class.

This would also make her unable to swim without super powers since she would sink like an iron rod. She would also sink in beach sand as well.

Comment: What if it was not sand or water, but something like pudding?

Comment: I believe women's muscles are in reality more dense than men's. But I am only now reading this is because of more "slow twitch" and less "fast twitch" muscles. Not simply  the same stuff packed into a smaller space.

Answer (score 1):

**Monkey woman.**

[image: yoimya as monkey woman]

Oh Mrs Crane you're a little monkey woman.  Yeah you're lean, mean and I bet you're not too far in between are ya?  Mmm.  Yes we all know the chimps are strong for their puny skinny size.  So too the anime girls.   They have the muscle structure of chimpanzees.

[Chimpanzee super strength and human skeletal muscle evolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5514706/)

> Unlike humans, chimpanzee muscle is composed of ∼67% fast-twitch fibers
> (MHC IIa+IId). Computer simulations of species-specific whole-muscle
> models indicate that maximum dynamic force and power output is 1.35
> times higher in a chimpanzee muscle than a human muscle of similar
> size. Thus, the superior mass-specific muscular performance of
> chimpanzees does not stem from differences in isometric
> force-generating capabilities or maximum shortening velocities—as has
> long been suggested—but rather is due in part to differences in MHC
> isoform content and fiber length. We propose that the hominin lineage
> experienced a decline in maximum dynamic force and power output during
> the past 7–8 million years in response to selection for repetitive,
> low-cost contractile behavior.

Chimp mask from https://www.facebook.com/ameliechabeauxmakeupsfx/photos/pcb.2650839231692628/2650839048359313/?type=3&theater

Anime girl:  https://www.vg247.com/genshin-impact-yoimiya-build-guide

Comment: I understand "you're lean, mean" but what does "too far in between" mean?

Comment: @Daron that is a fine question and one I must defer to Carl the assistant greenskeeper.  Let me introduce you.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9XcXniI3JQ

Comment: Perhaps it is a golf pun that didn't quite land. There are already two puns "green" and "you're a trap" in that clip.

Comment: @Daron  No I think it is just Bill Murray's zany improvising.  I cannot imagine a script writer in 1980 wrote any of those lines.